# TLS Certificate verification issues

Tags: tls1.2, x509certificate, dotnet-cli

I'm writing a gRPC microservice and i'm keen to test with grpcurl. I've installed Go SDK, started my microservice in developer environment and first of all getting a warning:

`warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[8]`

```
The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate
```

And when i'm trying to list my services i get the following:

`grpcurl localhost:7002 list`

```
Failed to dial target host "localhost:7002": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've tried to force trust through CLI:
dotnet dev-certs --trust --verbose

But got this:

`dotnet dev-certs https --trust --verbose`

Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was
not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.

[1] Listing certificates from CurrentUser\My

[2] Found certificates: 1 certificate
1) 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:33Z to 2024-07-12 19:52:33Z

- IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[3] Checking certificates validity

[4] Valid certificates: 1 certificate
1) 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:33Z to 2024-07-12 19:52:33Z

- IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[5] Invalid certificates: no certificates

[6] Finished listing certificates.

[1] Listing certificates from LocalMachine\My

[2] Found certificates: no certificates

[3] Checking certificates validity

[4] Valid certificates: no certificates

[5] Invalid certificates: no certificates

[6] Finished listing certificates.

[8] Filtered certificates: 1 certificate
1) 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:33Z to 2024-07-12 19:52:33Z

- IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[9] Excluded certificates: no certificates

[14] Valid certificates: 1 certificate
1) 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:33Z to 2024-07-12 19:52:33Z

- IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[15] Selected certificate: 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:33Z to
2024-07-12 19:52:33Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[29] Trusting the certificate to: 55504A6A1C23B4F3090C97DE007473BA35324F50 - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-07-13 19:52:
33Z to 2024-07-12 19:52:33Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true.

[45] Adding certificate to the trusted root certification authority store.

[31] An error has occurred while trusting the certificate: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StorePal.Add(ICertificatePal certificate)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Certificates.Generation.WindowsCertificateManager.TrustCertificateCore(X509Certificate2 certificate)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Certificates.Generation.CertificateManager.TrustCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate).
There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.`

.NET version 7.0.203
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Your problem is `Access denied`. If you are running on Windows, you must have Administrative permissions to run the command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust --verbose`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I gave myself administrator rules, but still can't work this out. I've tried running prompt as administrator and gave full access for rsa keys directory. Still have no luck

Comment: That means you now have a different error, which means create a new question.